# Pig load files using tuple's field

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I need help for following use case:

Initially we load some files and and process those records (or more technically tuples). After this processing, finally we have tuples of the form:

```
(some_field_1, hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kailashgupta/data/1/part-r-00000, some_field_3)
(some_field_1, hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kailashgupta/data/2/part-r-00000, some_field_3)
(some_field_1, hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kailashgupta/data/1/part-r-00001, some_field_3)
```

So basically, tuples has file path as value of its field (*We can obviously transform this tuple having only one field having file path as value OR to a single tuple having only one field with some delimiter (say comma) separated string*).

So now I have to load these files in Pig script, but I am not able to do so. Could you please suggest how to proceed further. I thought of using advanced `foreach` operator and tried as follows:

```
data = foreach tuples_with_file_info {
    fileData = load $2 using PigStorage(',');
    ....
    ....
};
```

However its not working.

**Edit:**
For simplicity lets assume, I have single tuple with one field having file name:

```
(hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kailashgupta/data/1/part-r-00000)
```

Comment: You can not write LOAD statement inside nested FOREACH, its not supported.

Comment: @Gaurav, any other solution(s)?

Comment: perhaps, preprocess the files and put them under 1 directory? or create dynamic PIG script with multiple load functions - 1 per each file - and then UNION all the data sources?

Comment: I did understand the question. You one i/p data determines the input file paths and you want to load those files. My above comment still stands valid.

Comment: @GauravPhapale, we can not preprocess, as which file to pick is not known at that time. This information is extracted from other inputs at run time. And could you clarify what you mean by "create dynamic PIG script with multiple load functions - 1 per each file"?

Comment: Kailash, I havent done this, but I've seen people creating PIG script file dynamically in Python script based on input files and then execute it from inside Python script. You might want to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, store the `tuples_with_file_info` into some file:

```
STORE tuples_with_file_info INTO 'some_temporary_file';
```

then,

```
data = LOAD 'some_temporary_file' using MyCustomLoader();
```

where
`MyCustomLoader` is nothing but a `Pig` loader extending `LoadFunc`, which uses `MyInputFormat` as `InputFormat`.

`MyInputFormat` is an encapsulation over the actual InputFormat (e.g. `TextInputFormat`) which has to be used to read actual data from the files (e.g. in my case from file hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kailashgupta/data/1/part-r-00000).

In `MyInputFormat`, override `getSplits` method; first read the actual file name(s) from the `some_temporary_file` (You have to get this file name from `Configuration`'s `mapred.input.dir` property), then update the same `Configuration` `mapred.input.dir` with retrieved file names, then return result from wrapped up InputFormat (e.g. in my case `TextInputFormat`).

**Note:** 1. You cannot use the `setLocation` API from the `LoadFunc` (or some other similar API) to read the contents of `some_temporary_file`, as its contents will be available only at run time.
2. One doubt may arise in your mind, what if `LOAD` statement executes before `STORE`? But this would not happen because if `STORE` and `LOAD` use same file in the script, `Pig` ensures that the jobs are executed in the right sequence. For more detail you may read section *Store-load sequences* on [Pig Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigMultiQueryPerformanceSpecification)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Pig out of the box to do it.

What I would do is use some other scripting language (bash, Python, Ruby...) to read the file from hdfs and concatenate the files into a single string that you can then push as a parameter to a Pig script to use in your LOAD statement. Pig supports globbing so you can do the following:

```
a = LOAD '{hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kailashgupta/data/1/part-r-00000,hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kailashgupta/data/2/part-r-00000}' ...
```

so all that's left to do is read the file that contains those file names, concatenate them into a glob such as:

```
{hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kailashgupta/data/1/part-r-00000,hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kailashgupta/data/2/part-r-00000}
```

and pass that as a parameter to Pig so your script would start with:

```
a = LOAD '$input'
```

and your pig call would look like this:

```
pig -f script.pig -param input={hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kailashgupta/data/1/part-r-00000,hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kailashgupta/data/2/part-r-00000}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Using Pig version 0.12.0 (6 years later), it didn't work with curly braces, but it worked by concatenation the file names without curly braces. This is FYI for the folks reading this solution with later version of Pig.